# Customize the Android contact picker

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts

I'd like to present a Contact picker, but add additional prompting when the picker is opened. On 1.5 the title is simply "Contacts".

I was thinking I could add an EXTRA_TITLE to the Intent which opens the picker, but it supposedly only works on ACTION_CHOOSER, not ACTION_PICK.

Or do I have to roll my own Contact picker?

Answer (score 0):

If you want functionality beyond what the built-in activities do, you must build your own version, and specify `IntentFilter`s that match those of the activity you wish to "mimic".

Be advised, this does not simply "replace" any built-in activity's functionality.  The system will automatically present a Chooser to the user, who **may or may not** pick your activity to complete the action.

Adding your own "extras" to a "system-replacement" activity has dubious value; everything else in the system will not know about your extras, and not send them!